# Using the word "inform" as a synonym for "instruct" - Is this wrong?

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis

I work in a section of my organization that involves writing of technical documents. Our organization recently put out a policy to avoid using the word "instruct" when referring to our clients as it's deemed as too strong of a word as our clients may see the documents as some point.

Instead, they recommend the use of the word "inform". The word "advise" is an alternative but it is not preferred.

The issue I have is I don't believe it is an exact synonym for instruct and I need to be able to explain exactly why.  I've looked through writing guides and I just can't explain in technical detail why it's wrong but my gut tells me. Of course, my gut could very well be wrong.

Example:
"Instruct the client to call customer service if they don't receive the email."

We now write that as:

"Inform the client to call customer service if they don't receive the email."

To me, that just seems awkward. I think it's because "inform" means to impart information so it can be a synonym for verbs like "tell" or "instruct" in some cases if it involves imparting information. So having the verb afterwards doesn't make sense to me.

I tried bringing this up but I was referred to a dictionary which lists "tell" as the primary synonym for "inform" and "Tell the client to call customer service" works well.

To me, the sentence should either be written as:
"Advise the client to call customer service"
or
"Inform the client that they must call customer service"

So, is my gut wrong? Is this a valid/unawkward way of writing?

If not, can anyone explain technically what the issue is?

Comment: I agree with you. _Tell_ has several meanings; _inform_ applies to the first definition [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tell), but _instruct_ applies to the third one.

Comment: I agree; if there is a sense of 'instruct' in 'instruct X to ...' that 'justifies' the claim for synonymity between 'instruct' and 'inform' buried somewhere in OED, it's so far from the default senses that its use violates a Gricean maxim. 'Tell X to ...' vs 'Tell X that ...'.  How about 'Recommend that the client call customer service ...'?

Comment: The issue starts with removing language that's either bossy or non-PC. Starting with that assumption, you gotta come up with substitutes like inform, advise, hint, whisper or wha-ever, but not because they are synonymous. I wouldn't ask friends to watch me *instruct* them on when to stop beating egg whites; I'd offer to *show* them.

Comment: I understand why your bosses want to avoid *instruct* (it may remind one of the instructor-student relation) and you are right that *inform* doesn't work in this context, but *tell* avoids both problems. It is not clear from your question whether your bosses have outlawed *tell* as well as *instruct*. If they haven't, using *tell* is the solution; if they have, you have a problem of workplace relations that is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: If you have to avoid tell you could use 'suggest that the client calls customer services'

Comment: @AndyM: You would need the subjunctive: *suggest that the client **call** customer services*, but even then, that makes the action optional, which is not what was intended.

Comment: You are correct; we *inform someone that...* or *instruct someone to...*. As you can see, you can swap in *tell* in both cases — but the thinking doesn’t stop there.

Comment: Would they let you say, "Advise the client to etc." or "Inform the client that they can etc."?

Comment: “*Inform the client that the next step is to call . . .”  Obviously the objective is to avoid treating the client as someone whom you instruct.